# Referencing Razor from a non-web application project in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

We're porting a class library project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5. The library, among other responsibilities, uses Razor to generate HTML emails from templates. We used to reference Razor from that class library project by depending on two NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.1.3" />
```

(We also had to setup applications using the class library to "preserve the compilation context" for Razor to work via `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>`.)

With .NET 5, we need to update these references, too. However, the corresponding NuGet packages no longer exist for version 5. Instead, ASP.NET Core [is now added as a `FrameworkReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference):

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

This is fine for web applications, but we're not actually building a web application here.

What's the right way to reference Razor in our scenario?

Comment: See: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/MiniRazor